# get_the_excerpt() inside WP_Query - link URL Incorrect

Tags: page-template

I have a custom `WP_Query` loop, to pull out specific `posts`, that is working exactly as expected.  The link can be retrieved from `get_permalink()`, as can any content that I'm requesting including `get_the_post_thumbnail` and `get_the_category`.

However, when I am calling `get_the`excerpt`, the "Continue Reading" URL for the links of **some** posts is being returned as the current page URL, not the URL of the post that it's supposed to link to.  Other posts work just fine, and the actual content that's excerpted from the posts with defective links is also fine.

If I enter in an actual excerpt, rather that allow Wordpress to create one, the link shows up correctly. When I then remove that excerpt again, the problem returns.

All pages are made in Page Builder, and about 50% of pages are affected. Even copying the page content entirely from a working post to a defective one doesn't work, nor does the inverse break a working post.

Any ideas?

```
while ($the_query->have_posts())
{
$the_query->the_post();

    $coverPost .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'medium_large'); //works

    $category = get_the_category(get_the_ID()); //works
    $coverPost .= '<h4>' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</h4>'; //works
    $coverPost .= '<h2>' . strtoupper(get_the_title()) . '</h2>'; //works
    $coverPost .= '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>'; //sometimes works
}
```

Comment: `get_the_excerpt()` does by default not add a link; https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt - please check your theme or plugins for related filter functions; see also https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Comment: Oh, really? This is running from a child theme of Coraline, so I'll investigate that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can remove read more link by adding this filter to functions.php then add permalink to your loop

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
return '..';   }add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I've already done as a work-around, but I'd rather the actual function worked properly.  I'm looking to see if the Coraline theme is the cause of this, as per the comment on the question.

Comment: the default has no link read more